# Radio Button setchecked cannot be set to true in Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to make a radio button toggle using setChecked().

setChecked(false) works fine but setChecked(true) doesn't work.

Also tried toggle(), even this doesn't uncheck the radio button.

I need a solution without using radio groups. Just a single radio button and on tapping should toggle its state.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void radioCheck(View v) {
    System.out.println("radioCheck");
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

//rb.toggle();

    if (rb.isChecked() == true) {
        rb.setChecked(false);
    }
    else {
        rb.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="radioCheck"
    android:text="Set me" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:onClick="radioCheck"
    android:text="On/ Off" />
```

Surprisingly, setChecked works when a button is used to uncheck the radio button but the same doesn't work when set on radio button.

Comment: Try to replace this code : if (rb.isChecked()){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're causing a infinite loop and stack overflow probably. The `setChecked` is all unnecessary, you don't need to toggle it yourself. The `onClick` is for reacting to a new selection, not checking/unchecking it yourself.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

if condition work true or false case so when you get isChecked() is already return true or false so no required to check with (== true) this things you have done wrong in your code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set me" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="radioCheck"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="On/ Off" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioButton radioButton1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        button2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }

    public void radioCheck(View v) {
        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
            radioButton1.setChecked(false);
        }
        else {
            radioButton1.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But radioCheck method is being called on click of a Button, not RadioButton

Comment: or just: rb.setChecked(!((RadioButton)v).isChecked());

Comment: @HareshChhelana This doesn't work on radio button click (same old problem still exists). When using the button the app crashes returning button stopped responding.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution to this problem. The basic functioning of radio buttons is that at least one of the should be selected. In my case, I had only one radio button and that's the reason why that can't be deselected. 

This functionality can only be achieved using check boxes.